# Is it bad to have a cyclical relationship?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key

I have 5 tables that have ended up with a cyclical relationship and I don't think that is ok.

I School is in one County.  A Distict has many Counties. A Teacher can teach in many Districts.

> STUDENTRECORD - RecordId, TeacherId, CountyCode
>
> COUNTY - CountyCode, CountyName, DistrictId
>
> DISTRICT - DistrictId, DistrictName
>
> TEACHER - TeacherId
>
> TEACHERDISTRICT - DistrictId, TeacherId

So the relationship goes from the StudentRecord, teacherid, to the district, to the county and back to the studentrecord.

I have built the database, populated the teacher, district and county tables, but I have not tried to insert a StudentRecord yet.  I just know I have not seen a db design with a circle relationship before and I think there is a reason for that.  I assume I have created a bad design.

Is a cyclical relationship a bad thing in database design?  If so, why?Thoughts on fixing?

EDIT:  I forgot the DistrictId in the COUNTY table, which completes the circle. Sorry for the incomplete question.  Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: The relationship that you describe here is not cyclical.  Specifically, as detailed above, COUNTY does *not* point to STUDENTRECORD, but the other way around.  Because COUNTY does not contain a `RecordId` pointer, but rather STUDENTRECORD does contain a CountyCode pointer.

Comment: Yes, see the answer by Damir, it's not a circle. It looks like but it's not. The foreign key constraints have an orientation, from the referencing table to the referenced one. Only if there is a cycle following the "arrows", it's a cycle.

Comment: See edits, I forgot to add the districtid in the county table.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the original model -- at least as worded in the question.

[image: school_county_1]

Though there is nothing cyclical here it does have few problems. For example, the model has no relationship between `County` and `District`, although you do state that "District has many Counties". It is also possible to have `StudentRecord {RecordId, TeacherId, CountyId}` such that that teacher does not teach in the district the county is located in.

---

One possible fix may look like this, though I do not think this would be complete solution, but it may be a good starting point. I will use predicates -- marked by **|** -- and constraints (italics) to describe the model. Predicates map to tables and constraints to PK,AK, FK.

**|** District (DistrictId) exists.

*District is identified by DistrictId.*

**|** County (CountyCode) is located in district (DistrictId).

*County is identified by CountyCode.*

*Each county is located in exactly one district; for each district that district may have more than one county.*

*If a county is locaeted in a district, then that district must exist.*

**|** Teacher (TeacherId) exists.

*Teacher is identified by TeacherId.*

**|** Teacher (TeacherId) is licensed to teach in district (DistrictId).

*For each teacher, that teacher may be licensed to teach in more than one district.*

*For each district, more than one teacher may be licensed to teach in that district.*

*If a teacher is licensed to teach in a district, then that teacher must exist.*

*If a teacher is licensed to teach in a district, then that district must exist.*

**|** School (SchoolId) is located in county (CountyCode), district (DistrictId).

*School is identified by SchoolId.*

*For each school, that school is located in exactly one county, district.*

*For each county, district; more than one school may be located in that county, district.*

*If a school is located in a county, district; then that county must be located in that district.*

**|** Teacher (TeacherId) teaches in school (SchoolId), in district (DistrictId).

*Each teacher may teach in more than one school in a district.*

*For each school in a district it is possible that more than one teacher teaches in that school.*

*If a teacher teaches in school in a district, then that school must be located in that district.*

*If a teacher teaches in school in a district, then that teacher must be licensed to teach in that district.*

**|** Student (StudentId) exists.

*Student is identified by StudentId.*

**|** Student (StudentId) attends school (SchoolId).

*Each student may attend more than one school, for each school is is possible that more than one student attends that school.*

*If a student attends school, then that student must exist.*

*If a student attends school, then that school must exist.*

**|** Student record (RecordId) was generated for student (StudentId) by teacher (TeacherID) in school (SchoolID).

*Student record is identified by RecordId.*

*If a student record was generated for a student by a teacher in a school, then that student must attend that school.*

*If a student record was generated for a student by a teacher in a school, then that teacher must teach in that school.*

[image: school_county_2]

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to have relationships with everyone. As long as there's a reason for that, meaning, as long as the concepts have an independent relationship amongst themselves. If your student lives in a county and you want to keep that info; and their teacher is a teacher in a different county, that's ok. But if the student must only have teachers in their own county, it's not ok.

You must be thinking about normalization. Check "[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)" for more details, might some of your questions as to why tables are designed in some ways.