# Two paths between two entities

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

In my db the entities are:

- designed_object: a generic designed object
- designed_object_param: a parameter related to the designed object with the type (param_type), the default value (param_value), the maximum and minimum value (param_max/min_value)
- real_object: an instance of the designed object
- real_object_param: the actual parameters of the instance (param_value)

They are related as follow (foreign key):

- designed_object - real_object: 1..n
- designed_object - designed_object_param: 1..n
- real_object - real_object_param: 1..n
- designed_object_param - real_object_param: 1..1

The problem is that there are two paths from real_object_param to designed_object:

- real_object_param -> real_object -> designed_object
- real_object_param -> designed_object_param -> designed_object

With this design, it is possible that, starting from the same real_object_param, the two paths point to two different rows if, for some bug, the real_object_param refers a wrong designed_object_param.
I know that this can be avoided through a trigger.
Is there any better design?

Thanks.

[image: entity-relationship]

Comment: Can you describe which columns are involved in the FK between `real_object_param` and `designed_object_param`?

Comment: in table real_object_param:FOREIGN KEY (id_designed_object_param) REFERENCES designed_object_param (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual schema, you could add a `designed_object_param` assigned to a different `designed_object`.

If you want a 1 - 1 constraint, add a `id_designed_object` field to the `real_object_param`, and compose the FK as `(id_designed_object, id_designed_object_param)`. This will ensure that only params of the designed object can be added to the `real_object_param`.

You can also add `id_designed_object` to the FK between `real_object_param` and `real_object` as `(id_object, id_designed_object)`. I think this covers all possibilities.

The final schema should be similar to this:

```
create temp table designed_object
(
    id_designed_object int not null PRIMARY KEY
);

create temp table designed_object_param
(
    id_designed_object int4 not null REFERENCES designed_object (id_designed_object),
    id_designed_object_param int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_designed_object, id_designed_object_param)
);

create temp table real_object
(
    id_real_object int4 not null,
    id_designed_object int4 not null REFERENCES designed_object (id_designed_object),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_real_object, id_designed_object)
);

create temp table real_object_param
(
    id_real_object int4 not null,
    id_real_object_param int4 not null,
    id_designed_object int4 not null,
    id_designed_object_param int4 not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_real_object, id_designed_object, id_real_object_param),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_real_object, id_designed_object) REFERENCES real_object (id_real_object, id_designed_object),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_designed_object, id_designed_object_param) REFERENCES designed_object_param (id_designed_object, id_designed_object_param)
);
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/GKU8783

Comment: The PK are wrong on `real_object`,  `real_object_param` -- the `id_real_object` is allowed to repeat in first one, but is assumed to be unique in the second one. so you can have PK (id_real_object, id_designed_object)  (1,1) (1,2) (two rows) but in the `real_object_param` only one (id_real_object, id_real_object_param) (1,1) is allowed.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic you're right, PK of `real_object_param` should be `PRIMARY KEY (id_real_object, id_designed_object, id_real_object_param),` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed few things here, just to make it easier for me to think. Most of it is self-explanatory. In essence, the problem and the solution is very similar to [the previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/is-it-bad-to-have-a-cyclical-relationship/158039#158039), with more detailed answer.

[image]